# 999+ ошибок. Read only asset has no meta file

Tags: unity3d

Писал скрипты для игры на Unity и вдруг увидел сообщение об ошибке. В консоли сначала было 999+ предупреждений и 128 ошибок типа:

```
 Read only asset Packages/nuget.mono-cecil/package_IObitDel_IObitDel.json has no meta file.
Packages/com.unity.multiplayer-hlapi/Tests/Runtime/GetCurrentRTTCallDoesntCrashWhenUseWebSockets/Resources/GetCurrentRTTCallDoesntCrashWhenUseWebSockets_PlayerPrefab_IObitDel_IObitDel.prefab has no meta file
```

и похожих.
 Но количество ошибок постоянно росло и через некоторое время их стало тоже 999+. При этом я абсолютно ничего не делал и размножались они сами по себе. Я пересоздал проект, но ошибки остались. И так сколько бы раз я не пересоздавал. Позже я снёс текущую версию Unity и установил заново и это тоже не помогло. Я даже переустановил unity hub, но это опять же не помогло.
Насколько я понял надо что-то изменить в manifest.json , но что - я не знаю.
В самом скрипте ошибок нет. По крайней мере компилятор VS 2017 их там не увидел.
Но если что, то вот:
1 скрипт

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class WeaponClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected float NumberOfDamageElements { get; set; }
    protected float VolumeOfStore { get; set;  }
    protected float DamageElementsPerSecond { get; set; }
    public virtual void Shoot()
    {
        //DamageElement bullet;
        //TODO: bullet's fly realization
    }
    public virtual void Reload()
    {
       // TODO: interaction with character class
    }
    public class DamageElement
    {
        protected float DamagePerElement { get; set; }
        protected Collider DamageZone { get; set; }
        protected Vector3 Speed = new Vector3();
    }
}

public class Flamethrower : WeaponClass
{
    public Flamethrower(float NumberOfDamageElements, float VolumeOfStore, float DamageElementsPerSecond)
    {
        this.NumberOfDamageElements = NumberOfDamageElements;
        this.VolumeOfStore = VolumeOfStore;
        this.DamageElementsPerSecond = DamageElementsPerSecond;
    }
    protected new float NumberOfDamageElements { get; set; }
    protected new float VolumeOfStore { get; set; }
    protected new float DamageElementsPerSecond { get; set; }
    public bool StoreIsEmpty = false;
    public override void Shoot()
    {
        //TODO: Realization of firethrow
    }
    public new class DamageElement
    {
        protected float DamagePerElement { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2 скрипт

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class M2A17Mechanics : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource FlamethrowerAudio;
    public AudioClip FlamethrowerStartSound;
    public AudioClip FlamethrowerLoopSound;
    public Flamethrower M2A17 = new Flamethrower(30f, 30f, 0f);
    private void Start()
    {
        FlamethrowerAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            FlamethrowerAudio.clip = FlamethrowerStartSound;
            FlamethrowerAudio.Play();
            while (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && !M2A17.StoreIsEmpty)
            {
                FlamethrowerAudio.Stop();
                FlamethrowerAudio.clip = FlamethrowerLoopSound;
                FlamethrowerAudio.Play();
                M2A17.Shoot();
            }
            FlamethrowerAudio.Stop();
        }

    }
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: После чего они появились. Что вы писали тогда. Покажите нам этот скрипт.

Comment: Изменил вопрос.

Comment: По ошибке видно что у этого `GetCurrentRTTCallDoesntCrashWhenUseWebSockets_PlayerPrefab_IObitDel_IObitDel` префаба отсутствует мета файл. Мета файл используется для прочтения  объекта в юнити. Попробуйте удалить этот префаб и создать заного.

Comment: А у вас есть такой префаб вообще?

Comment: Если то что сверху не работал кликайте на ошибку. Он либо вас переместит там где ошибка либо ничего не будет происходить. Тогда по одному копируйте то что в Assets и снимите с проекта. Если ошибка исчезнет значит ошибка была в этом объекте. Так будет легче его найти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, что совет пользователя Alt_F4 и помог бы мне, но я использовал другой метод - я просто удалил не только Unity и Unity Hub, но и все папки связанные с ними и Unity аккаунт.
И соответственно пересоздал и переустановил это всё. Больше у меня такой проблемы нет.